# How can I group the lines in a text file based on the contents of each line?

Tags: python, text, line

Assume I have a text file containing the following:

```
12277   17/06/2019  350 BJ201AB FMACRI                  
                    0   J   52  4081.15 166851
                    0   J   52  4496.64 166852
                    0   J   52  5139.07 166855
                    0   J   52  5773.82 166858
                    J   E   70  25  B159681
12509   21/06/2019  443 DH717WF BLANCO                  
                    B   J   42  5376.63 5164/A
12504   21/06/2019  443 EB631NF LUCCIG                  
                    B   J   44  5567.46 5165/A
                    0   J   52  5347.58 166950
                    0   J   52  4742.4  166953
                    0   J   18  1146.24 427876
                    0   J   4   0.4 427877
                    J   0   372 1   B159763
                    R   0   1567    1   B159764
```

Assuming I would read the file like this:

```
with open('/home/pexp1/mezzi/INPUT') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
data = [(line.rstrip()).split('\t') for line in lines]
```

What would be the correct approach to group every line that starts with something (an int, a string etc) with every other line underneath it, up until a new line that follows the above rule is found?
Assuming I would like to call the line that respects the rule and get everything in its group, what data structure would be best to group these lines together?

EDIT: Apologies for the lack of clarity.
If I run the code above I get this when I run `print(data)`:

```
[
    ['12277', '17/06/2019', '350', 'BJ201AB', 'FMACRI'],
    ['', '', '', '', '', '0', 'J', '52', '4081.15', '166851'],
    ['', '', '', '', '', '0', 'J', '52', '4496.64', '166852'],
    ['', '', '', '', '', '0', 'J', '52', '5139.07', '166855'],
    ['', '', '', '', '', '0', 'J', '52', '5773.82', '166858'],
    ['', '', '', '', '', 'J', 'E', '70', '25', 'B159681'],
    ['12509', '21/06/2019', '443', 'DH717WF', 'BLANCO'],
    ['', '', '', '', '', 'B', 'J', '42', '5376.63', '5164/A'],
    ['12504', '21/06/2019', '443', 'EB631NF', 'LUCCIG'],
    ['', '', '', '', '', 'B', 'J', '44', '5567.46', '5165/A'],
    ...
]
```

As you can see, it's a list of lists.
How can I group these items together, in such a way that lists that **contain** an item at index position 0 (in this case, `12277`, `122509`, etc) are grouped together with the lists that follow bellow them (with no elements at index pos. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)?

Example:

```
['12277', '17/06/2019', '350', 'BJ201AB', 'FMACRI']
```

grouped with 
`['', '', '', '', '', '0', 'J', '52', '4081.15', '166851']`, `['', '', '', '', '', '0', 'J', '52', '4496.64', '166852']`, etc. up until the next line containing an element at index 0: `['12509', '21/06/2019', '443', 'DH717WF', 'BLANCO']`

EDIT2: This is the solution I came up with:

```
shipments = []
shuttle_lst = []

for line in data[1:]:
    if len(line[0]) < 1:
        shipments.append(line)
    else:
        shuttle = data[data.index(line) - (len(shipments) + 1)]
        shipments.append(shuttle)
        new_lst = [lst for lst in shipments]
        shuttle_lst.append(new_lst)
        shipments.clear()
```

This creates a list of lists where each header becomes the last element of that list.

Comment: Every line in this example starts with "something" if you treat spaces as "something". Please define "something". Is it an integer? A digit? A non-space character?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56789731/edit) and show us an example of expected output.

Comment: The file seems to be kind of like a fixed width flat file, the `12277   17/06/2019  ` part is 20 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to group the lines based on the header line which is the one that does not start with space right?

Consider the following:

```
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

# A list of lists
data = []

with open('data.dat') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith(" ") or line.startswith("\t"):
            if not data:
                raise RuntimeError("Wrong data - first line is not legit")
            data[-1].append(line.split())
            continue

        # If here, this is a header line
        data.append([line.split()])

pp.pprint(data)
```

This prints:

```
[   [   ['12277', '17/06/2019', '350', 'BJ201AB', 'FMACRI'],
        ['0', 'J', '52', '4081.15', '166851'],
        ['0', 'J', '52', '4496.64', '166852'],
        ['0', 'J', '52', '5139.07', '166855'],
        ['0', 'J', '52', '5773.82', '166858'],
        ['J', 'E', '70', '25', 'B159681']],
    [   ['12509', '21/06/2019', '443', 'DH717WF', 'BLANCO'],
        ['B', 'J', '42', '5376.63', '5164/A']],
    [   ['12504', '21/06/2019', '443', 'EB631NF', 'LUCCIG'],
        ['B', 'J', '44', '5567.46', '5165/A'],
        ['0', 'J', '52', '5347.58', '166950'],
        ['0', 'J', '52', '4742.4', '166953'],
        ['0', 'J', '18', '1146.24', '427876'],
        ['0', 'J', '4', '0.4', '427877'],
        ['J', '0', '372', '1', 'B159763'],
        ['R', '0', '1567', '1', 'B159764']]]
```

The result is a list of lists (of lists!). Each 2nd level list first item is the header line while the rest are the lines in that group

Comment: I ended up writing something similar, only that the header line becomes the footer. Your solution is more legible than mine, that's for sure.